# Google Drive apply label to all files in folder/subfolder

Tags: google-drive-api

My organization is requiring that all files in Drive have one of several labels applied to them. It seems you can multi-select up to 100 files and apply a label, but is there any way to apply a label to all files in a folder/subfolder? Our folders are organized alphabetically, so there are only a handful of files in each subfolder, which leads to a lot of extra manual work going in and out of each folder to apply the label rather than just propagating it down to all files in the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify conditions based on which these files will be labeled, you could use DLP rules (https://support.google.com/a/answer/9655387?hl=en&ref_topic=9646660)

For example if you want to label as Confidential all files which include in the filename the world "Payments", you can create a rule with a regular expression like:
(\W|^)[Pp]ayment[s]{0,1}(\W|$), and assign the label "Confidential" automatically ,to existing and new files.